# How to use node.name within contact bodies?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

In my touchesbegan, if i click on the same SKShapeNode, depending on what name that SKShapeNode has at the time of being touched, it runs this code below.

```
if node.name == "0.5" {
"Do something here"

if node.name == "1.0" {
"Do something else here"
```

This code works fine. But I am trying to do something similar with contact bodies. At the moment I have a code like this:

```
  if ((contactBody1.categoryBitMask == 1) && (contactBody2.categoryBitMask == 3)) {

  if contactBody2.name == "0.5" {
  "Do something here"

  } else if contactBody2.name == "1.0" {
  "Do something else here"
```

However Xcode does not recognise ".name" for contact bodies like it does in my touches began method. It says "Value of SKPhysicsBody has no member 'name'"

How can I identify the ".name" of the contact body when it detects a contact between two objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reading the Physics Body’s Node](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/node)

I think you can use `node` property for this.

`contactBody2.node!.name`